# Google Maps - Get name of a company

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've searched the web and twisted my head 20 times, and has not found any solution. I really hope someone can help.
When I clik the map, I would like to get the name of the company at the address. The only thing I obtain is the address with Geocoding. I have also used the PlaceService, but I only get the address in the name-property.
When I click the map, an infowindow with the information is automatically displayed. Is it possible to obtain the name from this infowindow ?

When I put the name into a text-box , and use Autocomplete and getPlace, I succeed.

Here is a sample:

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 59.6643573, lng: 10.6115281},
        zoom: 13
    });

function mapClickedAddMarker(event) {

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var point = event.latLng;
geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': point
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
            service.getDetails({
              placeId: results[i].place_id
            }, function(place, status) {
              if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log(place.name);
              }
            });

        }

    } else {
        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
```

}

[InfoWindow- system created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8yea.png)

[names on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhGes.png)

Please help ..

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can run the code and reproduce the error? You could also add your code to a JSBin or JSFiddle and share that link.

Answer (score 0):

I eventally found a  solution to my problem. It was nearbySearch, that is a method in the PlacesService class:

Here is a link to a sample:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search